# Are all character encoding compatible with ascii, for at least a-z

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

Some charset don't have all the 128 first identical to ascii, but is A to Z and a to z, always in the sam position?

I had a plan to set apaches default charset to somting odd in my test envirement, for easy detecting sites that don't tell the browser what encoding it sending.
But so far, I can't find one that makes A to Z show up as someting else.

There is an other question close to the subject, but thats about all 128 ascii chars:
[Are ASCII characters always encoded the same way in all character encodings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775206/are-ascii-characters-always-encoded-the-same-way-in-all-character-encodings)

Answer (score 2):

No, EBCDIC from IBM is the famous exception.

Another testcase is UTF-16 Big Endian, which puts "A" at U+0041. ASCII would treat the first 00 as a NUL, which often is interpreted as an end-of-string.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. The encoding mentioned in the other answer, [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), has a very different layout, to pick just one example.

*Most* encodings you find in the wild on the web today are *probably* ASCII compatible. But there are encodings other than ASCII which are entirely incompatible too.